# adding image inside html canvas using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, canvas

i am trying to create an image canvas where user can zoom into the image, the code which i got from here [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/u5ogmh9a/), now i tried to add image inside it and  i did the following code:

```js
function draw(scale, translatePos) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  make_base(context);
}

function make_base(context) {
  var base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png';
  base_image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  var translatePos = {
    x: canvas.width / 2,
    y: canvas.height / 2
  };

  var scale = 1.0;
  var scaleMultiplier = 0.8;
  var startDragOffset = {};
  var mouseDown = false;

  // add button event listeners
  document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function() {
    scale /= scaleMultiplier;
    draw(scale, translatePos);
  }, false);

  document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function() {
    scale *= scaleMultiplier;
    draw(scale, translatePos);
  }, false);

  // add event listeners to handle screen drag
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
    mouseDown = true;
    startDragOffset.x = evt.clientX - translatePos.x;
    startDragOffset.y = evt.clientY - translatePos.y;
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
    mouseDown = false;
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
    mouseDown = false;
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    mouseDown = false;
  });

  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    if (mouseDown) {
      translatePos.x = evt.clientX - startDragOffset.x;
      translatePos.y = evt.clientY - startDragOffset.y;
      draw(scale, translatePos);
    }
  });

  draw(scale, translatePos);
};



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#wrapper").mouseover(function(e) {
    $('#status').html(e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY);
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #9C9898;
  width: 578px;
  height: 200px;
}

#buttonWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0px 0px 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onmousedown="return false;">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200">
  </canvas>
    <div id="buttonWrapper">
      <input type="button" id="plus" value="+"><input type="button" id="minus" value="-">
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2 id="status">
    0, 0
  </h2>
</body>
```

however the image is not getting displayed inside the canvas, can anyone please tell me what could be wrong in here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `draw` function never actually draws to the canvas. You get the canvas and context in the first 2 lines, but you need to call `drawImage` with the image to actually add it to the canvas itself.

I suspect you want to be calling `make_base` inside it like so:

```
function draw(scale, translatePos) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  make_base();
}
```

You also need to have the context in the same scope as you use it. At the moment, the variable `context` only exists inside the `draw` function and not the `make_base` function, so you can't access it from inside `make_base`.

You can pass it as a variable like so:

```
function draw(scale, translatePos) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  make_base(context);
}

function make_base(context) {
  var base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'a2.jpg';
  base_image.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Every time you want to change anything on an HTML canvas you need to call draw functions to change what's there.

Comment: Is the image in the correct folder for the "implied path" ? Is the script in the head element or the appropriate html element as its docs state?

Comment: i tried your code bro, still image not getting displayed

Comment: can u please edit the whole code and show an example over here

Comment: @ZubairNazerOliyat If your code isn't working now it's likely there is some other issue going on as Samuel Marchant suggests.
i'd recommend checking:
- making sure your script actually loads. Either check in your browser's dev tools to see if your script is loaded, or do some console logging
- making sure your image path is correct and loading. Is your image being served from `[domain]/a2.jpg`?
- Is your script erroring anywhere? If you follow through the data you will probably find the cause

Comment: image path is correct and console doesnt show any error

Comment: the image is showing now but the zoom in zoom out is not workng,i have updated my code with your code and have put it in the question, please check

Comment: You don't actually use your `scale` variable to scale the image. You'll need to multiply the width and height of the image by `scale` and then pass those arguments to `drawImage`